# How important is it to have authentication on a dockerized database

Tags: security, docker, database

The docker-compose example on the MongoDB [docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) has a root password provided to the database and the app, but as far as I know, with docker's networking, only the other containers defined in the compose file would have access to the database container.

So how important is it to have a password on the database if the container isn't exposed externally?

Comment: What's your threat model?

Comment: @Ginnungagap Most of the containers I run need access to the database, and if one of my containers gets breached I'd likely have a larger issue than no credentials on my database. There aren't any ways someone realistically would breach the host system, and the only thing exposed would be a reverse proxy also running in a container. Most of my question is just regarding best practices.